# email type validation not working when incorrect email is submitted to form

Tags: reactjs

I was working on a react app which needs a registration system. I have used the same process in every required function, and it has not worked in any of them. I want to debug this before I move on. This is the form for sending password to user's email if the user forgets their password.

```
const initialState = {
    email: ''
};

class EmailPassword extends Component {
    
    constructor(props) { 
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ...initialState

        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); 

    }

    render() {
        const { email } = this.state;

        const configAuthWrapper = {
            headline: 'Email Password'
        };
        
        return (
            <AuthWrapper {...configAuthWrapper}>
                <div className='formWrap'>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> 
                        <FormInput 
                            type = "email"
                            name = "email"
                            value = {email}
                            placeholder = 'Email'
                            onChange = {this.handleChange}
                        />
                    </form>

                    <Button type='submit'>
                        Send email
                    </Button>
                </div>

            </AuthWrapper>
        );
    }
}
```

This is what the output looks like, with no apparent validation of email when a wrong email is submitted:
[image: validation not working]

What it's supposed to show:
[image: What it's supposed to show]

Comment: Where is the code to validate password, or show error in case validation fails?

Comment: @KanishkAnand I believe it's an in-built thing? It's email validation, not password. When an incorrect password is submitted, `type = 'email'` is supposed to verify it. I am quite new to this, so I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `Button` was not wrapped inside the `form`.
The solution I used:

```
<AuthWrapper {...configAuthWrapper}>
    <div className='formWrap'>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> 
            <FormInput 
                type = "email"
                name = "email"
                value = {email}
                placeholder = 'Email'
                handleChange = {this.handleChange}
            />

            <Button type="submit">
                Send email
            </Button>
        </form> //form must wrap the button
    </div>

</AuthWrapper>
```